# How to force Active Directory to update users name?

Tags: active-directory

I had a users initials as their First and Last name, and they asked me to put their full name in.  I did. On my users list, it still shows the initials. When I open up the property window, it has their full name?

I know sometimes these changes are not done right away, but its been a few hours. How do I get these changes to go through?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the user list, select the user, right-click and select Rename.

Comment: That was it. I guess I figured when I changed it in the property window, that was all there was to it. Not very intuitive that I had to do this also. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are actually 6 fields that control user's name and username, and the only way in GUI to ensure you change them all is to do what Patrick and Vick Vega suggests. Just opening a user's properties and changing things doesn't cover it all.  Always better to F2 or r-click->rename in user list to see all the fields.

The key is that Full Name and Display Name are different fields, but not obvious until you have this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use F2 in Server 2012 and later to get to the "Rename" dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update "Display Name" field.